# How can I change the default starting folder for a specific application launched from finder on Mac

Tags: mac, finder, application-launch, folder-redirection, neovim

I would like to launch the Neovim-qt app and have it default to something other than the root directory ("/") on my MacBook.

On Windows, I can change the default directory from the "properties" requestor box - easy peasy. But I don't see a way to do that on the Mac.

Because it is Neovim, I can easily navigate to the folder I want to be in, but I usually just want to start in my user folder ("~") and not have to manually change directories every time I launch nvim-qt from the dock bar.

Also, there is probably a way to set the default starting directory in init.lua, but I'm not sure how to do that. Any help appreciated!

Comment: I don’t know anything about Neo vim itself, so maybe there are some applications, specific settings that you can apply. But, for a general purpose solution to this on a Mac, I cannot recommend Default Folder highly enough. I have no affiliation except as a customer for probably 10+ years. It lets you define a default folder for any application, or even a list of favorites that you can jump to quickly. But my favorite feature, is probably the one where in an open/save dialog box, you can click on a Finder window in the background and the dialog box will immediately switch to that folder.